# How does AWS Beanstalk use NPM when deploying a Nodejs App?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm curious about the overall workflow of an AWS Beanstalk deployment. I'm assuming it runs npm at some point to get the packages installed on the server(s). But I was just wondering if AWS Beanstalk uses the latest command of 'npm install --production' to install packages. Currently I have a packages.json file as shown below and would like to insure if possible that only the dependencies are being installed and not the devDependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "3.4.4",
  "jade": "*",
  "restify": "~2.6.0",
  "assert": "~1.0.0",
  "orchestrate": "0.0.2",
  "chance": "~0.5.3"
}, 
"devDependencies": {
  "mocha": "~1.15.1"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the Elastic Beanstalk environment runs `npm install` without the `--production` flag. This happens on the instance at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py` before any env customizations supplied by the developer (i.e., environment option settings) are exported, which means setting `NODE_ENV=production` in the EB Environment's configuration also does not prevent devDependencies from being processed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Definitely good if this were added as a feature. I realize too that the Node.js team kind of snuck that in there on us all.   ;)

Comment: This is not a correct answer (at least, today). The way to influence `npm install` is via variable `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` and not `NODE_ENV`. Elastic Beanstalk does support this, as I have noted in my own answer below.

Comment: update feb 2020: "By default, Elastic Beanstalk installs dependencies in production mode (npm install --production). If you want to install development dependencies on your environment instances, set the NPM_USE_PRODUCTION environment property to false."

Comment: `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py` there is no such directory or file on the instance. Can someone tell where can I see this?

Comment: @papabiceps I think the /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py file doesn't exist anymore in AWS Linux 2 and the functionality has moved somewhere else. Did you ever figure out the new file that this runs from? I'm trying to figure that out now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72466543/stop-ebs-linux-2-node-js-from-trying-to-do-npm-install

Answer (score 24):

You can get AWS Elastic Beanstalk to run `npm install` in production mode if you set the environment variable `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true`. You can do this through the Elastic Beanstalk web console.

Alternatively, save the following text to any file with suffix `.config` inside a directory called `.ebextensions` in the project root and you can achieve the same thing without having to set them every time in the web console:

```
option_settings:

  - option_name: NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION
    value: true
```

Note: make sure you're using spaces, not tabs, as it's YAML format.

I found that the time to update new node.js code in a t1.micro environment went down from about 5 minutes to 90 seconds, now that it wasn't installing all the devDependencies such as grunt, karma, mocha, etc.

Comment: In the most recent Elastic Beanstalk solution stack (64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Node.js) the ebnode.py script references a `NPM_USE_PRODUCTION` variable that defaults to 'true'.  Setting this to 'false' in your .config files will result in `npm install` being run without the `--production` flag.  I found no reference to a `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` variable, though it's possible it gets used elsewhere to set `NPM_USE_PRODUCTION`.  Neither variable seems to be mentioned in any of Amazon's configuration documentation.

Comment: Will this run the `postinstall`?

Comment: Apparently doesn't run `postinstall`, but it will run `prestart`. How have they managed to make npm usage so difficult?

Comment: Your answer is almost complete though this days as for 2021 you need to use the env var called NPM_USE_PRODUCTION and not NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION.

Answer (score 18):

In the new versions of Elastic Beanstalk Node's stacks, the configuration has changed, as pointed by @etreworgy's comment.

You can check the current behavior, by running inside an EC2 instance:

```
cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py | grep -A 5 PRODUCTION
```

It returns, as of today:

```
        if 'NPM_USE_PRODUCTION' not in npm_env:
            npm_env['NPM_USE_PRODUCTION'] = 'true'

        if npm_env['NPM_USE_PRODUCTION'] == 'true':
            print 'Running npm with --production flag'
            check_call([npm_path, '--production', 'install'], cwd=app_path, env=npm_env)
            check_call([npm_path, '--production', 'rebuild'], cwd=app_path, env=npm_env)
        else:
            print 'Running npm without --production flag'
```

So, currently, it uses the `npm install --production` by **default**.

For those ones that want to disable it (as I was when I went to this answer), you have to create a **anything.config** inside an `.ebextensions` folder at your project's root folder (where **anything** means really anything; node, npm, whatever you want), with the content:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
      option_name: NPM_USE_PRODUCTION
      value: false
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is so easy but solved the same problem for me.

Comment: `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py` there is no such directory or file on the instance. Can someone say where can I see this file?

Comment: I wrote this 4 years ago, I wouldn't be surprised if they changed it. I no longer use EBS so I can't confirm, but in any case the rest of the answer is still valid, the --production flag is used by default and you can disable it using NPM_USE_PRODUCTION as seen here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-dependencies.html

Answer (score 1):

An additional option is to use npm-shrinkwrap, which has the additional benefit of letting you lock your dependencies at the same time.

AWS Elastic Beanstalk [suggests it here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html#nodejs-platform-shrinkwrap).

Comment: The referenced documentation also states that npm-shrinkwrap will speed up deployments as npm install will only need to executed once.