# Elastic Beanstalk to run 'concurrently' command via npm script

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my React + API server application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and experiencing some trouble right now.

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/) and I configured my npm scripts as such:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\" ",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "client": "node start-client.js"
},
```

However, EC2 seems to be not able to find the `concurrently` command, when I read the logs for the failure.

[Concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently) is installed as dev-dependencies but I understand that Elastic Beanstalk installs dev-dependencies as well unless asked otherwise.

With some googling, I came down to a suspicion that EC2 instance does not have the location of the installed node packages in its PATH but I am not quite sure how to solve this issue.

EDIT: I copied the error log from EBS log console.

```
\> kid-server@0.0.0 start /var/app/current
\> concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client" 
sh: concurrently: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! kid-server@0.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client" `
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the kid-server@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm update check failed
Try running with sudo or get access
to the local update config store via
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /tmp/.config
```

Comment: Can you add the logs that describe your error?

Comment: @toddg I edited my post and have added the error log you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266719/4228969) posted on SO, Elastic Beanstalk now **defaults** to running `npm install --production`. So you have two options to get npm package, concurrently, installed.

1. Add it to your production dependencies.
2. Instruct Elastic Beanstalk to not add the `--production` flag.

Option 1 is easier to implement (though may not meet your requirements). Option 2 would involve adding a `any.config` (name doesn't matter) file to a `.ebextensions` directory in your project root that contains the following yaml:

```
option_settings:
- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
  option_name: NPM_USE_PRODUCTION
  value: false
```

If you have ssh set up for your EB instance, ssh into it and navigate to `/var/app/current/node_modules`. You will likely see that `concurrently` is not there.

Comment: Great answer. I was able to install the concurrently package with the option you suggested.